# How to reshape or transpose select columns in a dataset while making calculations?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

[I have a dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDdGl.png) containing sales records for each sales associate, split by country, date (year and month), and customer segment. I can't figure out a way to aggregate the data into a wide format where each row is unique only to date and a sales person, with the calculated total sales revenue and % for each customer segment like so:

[image: like so].

Here is the CSV for the dataset:

```
Year,Month,Country,Associate,Sales Revenue,Customer Segment
2015,1,USA,Bill,20,Enterprise
2015,1,USA,Bill,10,Enterprise
2015,1,Germany,Bill,5,Consumer
2015,1,USA,Bill,5,Enterprise
2015,1,Germany,Ted,5,Consumer
2015,1,USA,Bill,10,Consumer
2015,1,Germany,Bill,5,Consumer
2015,1,Germany,Ted,20,Enterprise
2015,1,Germany,Ted,20,Consumer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this, but essentially you need to `group_by` the columns whose values should not change and then `summarise` to create the new variables.

You can either type everything and subset to the cases you care about:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv('Year,Month,Country,Associate,Sales Revenue,Customer Segment
2015,1,USA,Bill,20,Enterprise
2015,1,USA,Bill,10,Enterprise
2015,1,Germany,Bill,5,Consumer
2015,1,USA,Bill,5,Enterprise
2015,1,Germany,Ted,5,Consumer
2015,1,USA,Bill,10,Consumer
2015,1,Germany,Bill,5,Consumer
2015,1,Germany,Ted,20,Enterprise
2015,1,Germany,Ted,20,Consumer')

df %>% 
    group_by(Year, Month, Country, Associate) %>% 
    summarise(`Total Sales Revenue` = sum(`Sales Revenue`), 
              `Enterprise Sales %` = sum(`Sales Revenue`[`Customer Segment` == 'Enterprise']) / 
                  `Total Sales Revenue`* 100, 
              `Consumer Sales %` = sum(`Sales Revenue`[`Customer Segment` == 'Consumer']) / 
                  `Total Sales Revenue` * 100)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#> # Groups:   Year, Month, Country [?]
#>    Year Month Country Associate `Total Sales Revenue` `Enterprise Sales %`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>                     <dbl>                <dbl>
#> 1  2015     1 Germany Bill                         10                  0  
#> 2  2015     1 Germany Ted                          45                 44.4
#> 3  2015     1 USA     Bill                         45                 77.8
#> # ... with 1 more variable: `Consumer Sales %` <dbl>
```

...or do it more programmatically with `tidyr::spread` (which will scale to more variables better):

```r
df %>% 
    janitor::clean_names() %>% 
    group_by(year, month, country, associate, customer_segment) %>% 
    summarise(revenue = sum(sales_revenue)) %>% 
    mutate(percent = revenue / sum(revenue) * 100) %>% 
    spread(customer_segment, percent) %>% 
    summarise_all(sum, na.rm = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#> # Groups:   year, month, country [?]
#>    year month country associate revenue Consumer Enterprise
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1  2015     1 Germany Bill           10    100          0  
#> 2  2015     1 Germany Ted            45     55.6       44.4
#> 3  2015     1 USA     Bill           45     22.2       77.8
```

Comment: Thanks! What is `janitor::clean_names()` for?

Comment: I got sick of typing backticks

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can I ask why in two examples you `group_by` by different columns. Namely, in the `tidyr::spread` example, you add `customer_segment` to the list, vs not doing so in the first example...

Comment: The first uses explicit subsetting to create the two percent columns. The second first calculates the sums per segment. That `summarise` call strips off the last group, so then it can go right into the `mutate` grouped by year, month, country, and associate to add a percent column. Reshaping to wide form does not change grouping, and the last `summarise` adds the revenue from the different segments and drops the `NA`s inserted in the percent columns. Note both are left grouped by year, month, and country—the last `summarise` strips off the `associate` grouping.